# Using the remainder theorem to prove a quadratic is a factor of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring, prime-factorization

For example, if I have $P(x) = 3x^4 + 5x^3 -17x^2 -13x + 6$ then to show that $x^2 + x - 6$ is a factor I individually show that $x+3$ and $x-2$ are factors using the factor theorem (i.e. $P(-3) = 0$ and $P(2) = 0$).

However, if $x+3$ and $x-2$ are individually factors, why does that conclude their product would be a factor?

Because I have learnt if two individual numbers are factors, they also need to be "coprime" for the product to be a factor.

(For example: $12$ is divisible by both $6$ and $12$ but not their product $72$)

How would you know that $x+3$ and $x-2$ are coprime? E.g. for $x=7$ they do not seem to be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: e.g. for $x=6$ they are; if $d|x+3$ and $d|x-2$, then $d|(x+3)-(x-2)=5$; by the way, $12$ is divisible by both $6$ and $2$ and so is their product, so proving factors are coprime suffices to prove the product is a factor, but the product does not *need* to be coprime

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Ohh I see. I didn't think of that. But then how would we know that the product of those two factors will be a factor if they are coprime for some values of $x$ and not for others?

Comment: I don't think them individually being factors can conclude their product is a factor without some other reasoning?

Comment: What's your context / knowledge here? Ring theory in general, or specifically studying properties of polynomials?

Comment: I haven't done Ring theory, just properties of polynomials and a little bit of discrete math (where i learnt if $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1 $ and $p|m$ and $q|m$ then $pq|m$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x+3$ and $x-2$ (or any two distinct monic polynomials of degree $1$) are coprime **as polynomials**.  That is, there is no polynomial of positive degree that divides both of them.  Indeed, $(x-2)-(x+3)=-5$.  If $P(x)$ is a polynomial that is divisible by both $x-2$ and $x+3$, i.e. there are polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $P(x) = (x-2) q(x) = (x+3) r(x)$, we have
$$ (x+3) r(x) = P(x) = (x-2)(q(x)) = (x+3) q(x) -5 q(x)$$
so $$ q(x) = (x+3)(q(x)-r(x))/5$$
and $$P(x) = (x-2) q(x) = (x-2)(x+3)(q(x)-r(x))/5$$
is divisible by $(x-2)(x+3)$.

Comment: perhaps I should have asked OP, but are we talking about polynomials in $\mathbb Z[X]? \;\mathbb Q[X]?\; \mathbb R[X]?\;\mathbb C[X]$?